# laravel csrf_token mismatch when getting url request using curl in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, curl, laravel-5.4, csrf-protection

Sorry for my bad english. I think same question but with different idea have asked, but my idea is different. What I am asking is I have compile the laravel url in wordpress using curl request. please see my code to better understand what i am trying to say.

```
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
     <head>
        <!-- ImportInWordpressHeaderStart -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        <!-- ImportInWordpressHeaderEnd -->
       </head>
   <body> .......
         //here is my complete html part ignore it.


    <!-- ImportInWordpressFooterScriptStart -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('frontend/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#login form").on('submit', function (e){
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: $(this).attr('method'),
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: "json", ........... // the rest ajax code.

    <!-- ImportInWordpressFooterScriptEnd -->
```

The upper part of the code is completly in laravel which is working perfectly. Now see what i have done in wordpress theme header and footer.

```
<?php  
//Laravel Home url 
$url = "http://example.com/home";  
$ch = curl_init();  

// set URL and other appropriate options  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

// grab URL and pass it to the browser  
$output = curl_exec($ch);  

//Regular expression to excerpt the targeted portion  
preg_match('/<!-- ImportInWordpressFooterStart -->(.*?)<!--ImportInWordpressFooterEnd -->/s', $output, $footer);  
preg_match('/<!-- ImportInWordpressFooterScriptStart -->(.*?)<!-- ImportInWordpressFooterScriptEnd -->/s', $output, $script);
// close curl resource, and free up system resources  
curl_close($ch);  
?> 

<?php echo $footer[0]; 
      wp_footer();
      echo $script[0];
?>
```

Now in laravel when i clicked on login it is logged in perfectly but when i try to do the same in wordpress it gives me **token mismatch error**

```
 http://example.com/wordpress
```

The wordpress and laravel are both in same domain i don't want to create the same laravel header footer again in wordpress. any better idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, your main domain is `example.com`  and runs on Laravel while  the  `example.com/wordpress`  runs one wordpress? 

Also, how is the database setup ?  Are both apps sharing the same user information? I have a solution in either case

Comment: Yes every thing on the same domain, and both laravel and wordpress tables are on single database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each cookie session has its own csrf token, and you seemingly make no attempt to transfer the cookie session id recieved by curl to the browser, or vise-versa. thus the browser will attempt to login with it's own cookie session, and with the csrf token of curl's cookie session, that definitely wont work.

solution: make curl fetch the csrf token using the cookies of the browser.

```
$str='';
foreach($_COOKIE as $n=>$v){
    $str.=$name.'='.$v.'; ';
}
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,$str);
```

- note that if the page where you get the csrf token sends any new Set-Cookie headers, curl will not transfer those headers to the browser unless you write some code to explicitly do this. for example, if the url where you fetch the cookie session also regenerate the session id of the browser, and you dont transfer the new id to the browser, it will effectively logout the browser.

Comment: hi hanshenrik. I tried to dump the cookie and i am getting laravel_session and XSRF-TOKEN in the array. still not getting the csrf_token. I also tried to send this using ajax header but it wont receive. with your code my session is working fine but not login still.